# R- How to move value in a specific column to a different row based on a value in a different column

Tags: r, dataframe

Let's say I have the following data frame:

```
Seconds = c(0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3) 
Markers= c("NA", "NA", "Start", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA") 
df = data.frame(Seconds, Markers)
```

I want to move the value indicated by 'Start' in column Markers down its column (or a new column) a difference of 0.5 Seconds. Where this could be one result:

```
Seconds = c(0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3) 
Markers2= c("NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "Seconds", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA") 
df2 = data.frame(Seconds, Markers2)
```

Or this would work to if it's easier to accomplish:

```
Seconds = c(0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3) 
Markers2= c("NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "Seconds", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA") 
df3 = data.frame(Seconds, Markers, Markers2)
```

I thought maybe I could do something like this:

```
 df$MarkerReal <- NA
 df$MarkerReal [which(df$Markers == 'Start') + 5] <- 'Start'
```

This works for this example, but the real data I'm working with is time sensitive in milliseconds with thousands of rows. There isn't a specified amount of rows I need to move it, but rather base it off the value, in this example moving it by half a second.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an option:

```
curr.pos <- which(df$Markers == "Start")[[1]]  # taking first "Start" in case you have more than one
new.pos <- with(df, max(which(Seconds <= Seconds[[curr.pos]] + 0.5)))
df$Markers[c(curr.pos, new.pos)] <- c("NA", "Start")
```

Produces:

```
   Seconds Markers
1      0.0      NA
2      0.1      NA
3      0.2      NA
4      0.3      NA
5      0.4      NA
6      0.5      NA
7      0.6      NA
8      0.7   Start
9      0.8      NA
10     0.9      NA
11     1.0      NA
12     1.1      NA
13     1.2      NA
14     1.3      NA
```

This of course assumes your DF is sorted by the `Seconds` column.

As a side note, you should consider using real NAs (i.e. `NA_character_`) as opposed to strings with an "NA" value.

Comment: This works great. I like your comment about the just-in-case I have more Starts. I do have more of them. Is it possible to move all of them uniformly with one line instead of running them all individually?

Comment: @ejgennri, I'm afraid that is likely a non-trivial change, especially given the possibility that you might end up shifting one start on top of another.

Comment: @ejgennri, you can probably do something like `sapply(which(df$Markers == "Start"), function(x) with(df, max(which(Seconds <= Seconds[[x]] + 0.5))))` to get a vector with all the new positions, then, set `Markers` to `NA`, and then do something like `"df$Markers[all.positions] <- "Start"` where `all.position` was computed by the `sapply`.